# Parse Response via rest template exchange

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, microservices

How to create a POJO class Of below mentioned JSOn Structure by a REST Service. Using RestTemplate.exchange i need to parse this in my java.class file and get approved_by value and use in java code. Below is the response structure:

```
{
    "approval_rules_overwritten": true,
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "rule_type": "RuleTest",
            "approvals_required": 2,

            "approved_by": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "username": "ABC_XYZ",
                    "state": "active",
                }
            ],
            "approved": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a class representing this JSON ?

In quick in the same class file (different classes would be best in different files)

```
    public class Response {

        private Boolean approval_rules_overwritten;
        private List<Rule> rules;

        public static class Rule {
            private Integer id;
            private String name;
            private String rule_type;
            private Integer approvals_required;
            private List<Approval> approved_by;
            private Boolean approved;

            public static class Approval {
                private String id;
                private String name;
                private String username;
                private String state;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also remember to add getters and setters on each class.

Now you can do your classic request:

```
 ResponseEntity<Response> = restClient.exchange(request, Response.class);
```

and you would get your response.

You now only have to build your rest template and also to catch exceptions that could be thrown from the exchange request.